# YAML - keep text formatting in new document

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

What i have:

```
a: some meta info
b: more meta info
c: actual nicely
   formatted text that
   has line breaks
```

I'm looking to move `c` to a new YAML document by using doc separator ---

```
a: some meta info
b: more meta info
---
actual nicely
formatted text that has line breaks 
and so on
```

But when I use 2nd alternative, I lose formatting like new lines etc.

Is there a way I can use the latter YAML approach format and keep line breaks?

I'm currently using ruamel.yaml library to read this yaml and below function to load my file.

> yaml.load_all(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the line breaks to be in your loaded value I recommend to make the second document a literal style scalar.

If you have `input.yaml`:

```
a: some meta info
b: more meta info
--- |
actual nicely
formatted text that
has line breaks
```

then this program:

```
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

path_name = Path('input.yaml')


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
for data in yaml.load_all(path_name):
    print(repr(data))
```

gives:

```
ordereddict([('a', 'some meta info'), ('b', 'more meta info')])
'actual nicely\nformatted text that\nhas line breaks\n'
```

Please note that some YAML libraries do (incorrectly) assume that a literal style scalar at the root level of a document needs to be indented.